# Python Tkinter _tkinter.TclError on canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm writing a Tkinter interface to display heat-maps and histograms that I have generated, I have come across a problem that I think I may have narrowed down to a particular line of code.

```
root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Meteorites")


f = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)


# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

Above  is the part that seems to be causing the error,
in particular the canvas = FigureCanvasTkagg
With this removed there are no errors at all.

```
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, root )
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)



def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

button = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Quit', command=_quit)
button.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace.

Comment: you are calling `Tk.mainloop()` at the end of your main routine? shouldn't that be `root.mainloop()` ?

Answer (score 0):

root = tk.tk() can you tell me what you are trying to do by accesing tk from tk? In my opinion it seems kind of unneeded i would try messing with that.